# Alternating bilinear form with wedge product. equality problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

Let $\phi : \textbf{R}^4 \otimes \textbf{R}^4 \rightarrow \textbf{R}$ be an alternating bilinear form.

Prove that there exist linear maps $\alpha, \beta :\textbf{R}^4  \rightarrow \textbf{R}$ with $\phi = \alpha \wedge \beta$ if and only if $\phi \wedge \phi = 0$

Can somebody help me solving this one?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\phi \wedge \phi$? Wouldn't that be a map $(\mathbb{R}^4 \otimes \mathbb{R}^4) \wedge (\mathbb{R}^4 \otimes \mathbb{R}^4) \to \mathbb{R} \wedge \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: Also, wouldn't you want that $\phi = \alpha \otimes \beta$? It appears that $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^4 \wedge \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R} \wedge \mathbb{R}$, but $\alpha \otimes \beta$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^4 \otimes \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{R}$.